# How to sort goods at the lowest price?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AONX.png

I'm using code this code

```html
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_name_args');
function woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_name_args($args)
{
  if (isset($_GET['orderby'])) {
    switch ($_GET['orderby']):
      case 'name_list_asc':
        $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
        $args['order'] = 'ASC';
        $args['meta_key'] = 'courses-page_description_start_date';
        break;
      case 'price-desc':
        $args['orderby'] = '_regular_price';
        
        $args['order'] = 'DESC';
        $args['type'] = 'product';
        $args['meta_key'] = '_price';
        
        break;
      case 'name_list_desc':
        $args['orderby'] = 'title';
        $args['order'] = 'DESC';
        $args['meta_key'] = '';
        break;
    endswitch;
  } else {
    $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
    $args['order'] = 'ASC';
    $args['meta_key'] = 'courses-page_description_start_date';
  }

  return $args;
}
```

The price used is variable.
$product->get_variation_sale_price('min', true)

https://litschool.stebnev.ru/webinars/?orderby=price-desc

The site will be aimed at Europe and Russia. Please do without politics

Answer (score 0):

For sorting by the lowest price I mean for case 'price-desc'

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'sort_by_lowest_price' );

function sort_by_lowest_price( $args ) {
    $args['type']       = 'product';
    $args['meta_key']   = '_price';
    $args['orderby']    = 'meta_value_num';
    $args['order']      = 'asc'; 
 
    return $args;
}
```

Comment: sort by smallest orderby=price works great out of the box but not for the largest to the smallest /webinars/?orderby=price-desc question is ?orderby=price-desc not working correct. please help